How to prove the integral $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1+x^{2})\ln(1+x)}{x^{4} -x^{2} +1}\,dx\ = \frac{\pi \ln(2+\sqrt{3} )}{6} $
I am to prove that $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1+x^{2})\ln(1+x)}{x^{4} -x^{2} +1}\,dx\ = \frac{\pi \ln(2+\sqrt{3}) }{6}$$
I tried to split it, into $$\frac{1}{2} (\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^{2}-\sqrt{3}x+1}\,dx\ +\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^{2}+\sqrt{3}x+1}\,dx) $$
but I can't figure out how to solve it further.
Any help would be appreciated!

It's already been solved here.

@user773458 Oh, I couldn't find it anywhere. Thanks!
